# Argument null exception using Dapper at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.Emit

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, dapper

I am using Dapper 1.50.2 to connect to MySQL database and issued very strange error in this method

```
public new IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string sql, object param = null, bool buffered = true)
{
    IEnumerable<T> result = null;
    using (var connection = Database.GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        result = connection.Query<T>(sql, param, null, buffered, 500, null);
        connection.Close();
    }      
    return result.Where(x => EntityValidator.Validate(x));
}
```

where T was OldOrderConfirmation

```
public class OldOrderConfirmation : OldBaseEntity
{
    [MapToColumn("order_id")]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("order_number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("user_id")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("currency_code")]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("user_po")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("discount_value")]
    public decimal TotalDiscount { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("order_shipping")]
    public decimal DeliveryCosts { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("shipping_tax")]
    public decimal VATShipping { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("order_payment")]
    public decimal Reduction { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("payment_tax")]
    public decimal VATReduction { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("shipping_method_id")]
    public int ShippingMethodId { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("bemerkungen")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("order_date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("adminstatus")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("deliverydate")]
    public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    [MapToColumn("license_client")]
    public int Licensee { get; set; }
}
```

Error (ArgumentNullException: meth is null) occured at connection.Query method with the following stack trace:

```
at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.Emit(OpCode opcode, MethodInfo meth)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetTypeDeserializerImpl(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.GetReader(IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.GetReader(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetTypeDeserializer(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetDeserializer(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__125`1.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)

* No need in next lines *
```

After different attempts to fix it (upgrade and downgrade Dapper, changing target framework, clean/rebuild, relaunch Visual studio), I figured out that removing (and even renaming) one specific field from model fixed the error.

```
[MapToColumn("order_date")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Maybe problem could occur due to 'Date' word as reserved in MySQL or something like this, but I had this code working on another MySQL database!

Additional info: 'order_date' column is of type DATETIME

So I ask for some explanation why this error occured or at least could occur.

Comment: oof; short answer would be "I don't know, but I'm intrigued"; longer answer would be "log it as a bug on dapper, and I'll take a look when I can"

Comment: Still not working in 2020.

Comment: 3 years later I am trying to reproduce the issue but can't any db that it can be reproduced with. If someone has this issue too, please contact me to let me know some details about MySQL version/db schema etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in 2021, with still the same `ArgumentNullException` about `meth`. The only answers I found were about a property named `Date`, which I didn't have.

My mistake was trying to deserialize into a class with only a constructor with parameters and non-settable properties (the class was copied from somewhere else).

```cs
public class Foo {
    public Foo(string bar) { this.Bar = bar; }
    public string Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

The solution was simply to change to a parameterless constructor and add public setters to the properties.

```cs
public class Foo {
    public Foo() { }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```