# How can I map a Dapper QueryFirst to a class?

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to map a `QueryFirst` call to this entity,

```
public class QueueItem
{
    public long Id { get; }
    
    public string Item { get; }
    
    [Column("type_id")]
    public int TypeId { get; }
}
```

I have also set this up for the `Column` attribute to work,

```
Dapper.SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(
    typeof(QueueItem),
    new Dapper.CustomPropertyTypeMap(
        typeof(QueueItem),
        (type, columnName) =>
            type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(prop =>
                prop.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                    .OfType<ColumnAttribute>()
                    .Any(attr => attr.Name == columnName) || prop.Name == columnName)));
```

Dapper throws an internal exception,

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'meth')
   at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.Emit(OpCode opcode, MethodInfo meth)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GenerateDeserializerFromMap(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing, ILGenerator il) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 3289
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetTypeDeserializerImpl(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 3075
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.GetReader(IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.cs:line 153
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.GetReader(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.cs:line 50
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetTypeDeserializer(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 3026
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetDeserializer(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1789
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryRowImpl[T](IDbConnection cnn, Row row, CommandDefinition& command, Type effectiveType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1192
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryFirst[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 741
```

I have tried adding `Column` attribute for all properties, the outcome is the same.

The fluent mapping approach results in the same exception.

Dapper initialization (with fluent mapping):

```
FluentMapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.AddMap(new QueueItemMap());
});
```

Call to QueryFirst:

```
public bool TryGetItem(out QueueItem item)
{
    const string sql = @"
            SELECT *
            FROM `queue_items` 
            WHERE `processed_at` IS NULL AND `completed_at` IS NULL ORDER BY `id` ASC
            LIMIT 1;";
    
    using var dbConnection = _dbConnection;
    item = dbConnection.QueryFirst<QueueItem>(sql);
    return item != null;
}
```

Comment: Where did u store u sqlmapper code in your app so it would only run once?

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to solve this.

#### Adding map for one specific class

Try using `Dapper.FluentMap` extension (NuGet) to make this a bit easier.

See [*medium.com* post about it](https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-columns-mapping-1cd45dfd51d6). Summing up information from it, first create a map:

```
internal class QueueItemMap : EntityMap<QueueItem>
{
    internal QueueItemMap()
    {
        Map(qi => qi.TypeId).ToColumn("type_id");
    }
}
```

Then add it when configuring services:

```
FluentMapper.Initialize(config =>
    {
        config.Add(new QueueItemMap());
    });
```

This should auto-map other properties as usual, but "type_id" column will be used for `TypeId` member.

#### Mapping PascalCase to snake_case for every member

If you want to generally use this convention that `multiword_column_name` would be mapped to `MultiwordColumName` property, use

```
Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
```

when initializing dapper.

Comment: HI! Thanks for that, although fluent mapping results in the exact same exception being thrown internally by Dapper. I just tested it and got `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'meth')` again.

Comment: Are you sure the error is thrown by this map and not other mapped model? As it is not finding property `meth`, from what I assume there's model with `Meth` property, but database query doesn't return `meth` column.

Comment: So the only query I have in my application is the one that maps to the only model `QueueItem`, I don't have a `Meth` property anywhere. I removed my previous attempt before switching to fluent mapping.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide Dapper initialization code as well as how you call `QueryFirst` ?

Comment: Can't think of a reason, sorry. Maybe try installing older version of Dapper as it might be bug inside the Dapper lib.

Comment: I've tried 3 different versions all resulting in the same exception. I've created an issue on the github page, hopefully it will get picked up.

Comment: Where does this `meth` come from? Is it the name of a column in your table?

Comment: @silkfire no, there are plenty more questions on SO stating the word 'meth' in their exception, it is nothing to do with my code. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700250/argument-null-exception-using-dapper-at-system-reflection-emit-dynamicilgenerato

Answer (score 0):

I do not recomend using * on select statements, specially in this type of situation when you want map the result to a typed class.

Dapper is pretty good at mapping queries to classes without necessity of mapping packages, try do this:

Clear all your mapping classes and calls,

Leave the class like this:

```
public class QueueItem
{
    public long Id { get; }
    
    public string Item { get; }
    
    public int TypeId { get; }
}
```

And change the select statement to this:

```
    SELECT `ID` AS ID, 
           `ITEM` AS ITEM,
           `TYPE_ID` AS TYPEID
        FROM `QUEUE_ITEMS` 
            WHERE `PROCESSED_AT` IS NULL AND `COMPLETED_AT` IS NULL ORDER BY `ID` ASC
            LIMIT 1;
```

*Dapper is case insensitive to mapping, so dont worry about casing

If this dont work, you can try leave the changes as above and instead of doing this

```
var item = dbConnection.QueryFirst<QueueItem>(sql);
```

Try doing this and see if the error still occours:

```
var item = dbConnection.QueryFirst<dynamic>(sql);
```

As well, by using QueryFirst you have to assume that it aways will find something in the database, otherwise it will throw an exceotion, in your case youre checking for null values, so use QueryFirstOrDefault.

Comment: You should not do it like this due to the inability to map enums (I use a lot), and inability to map booleans since MySQL doesn't support the datatype. Sure you could cast, but its not ideal.

Comment: MySQL does support boolean types, althought it is store as tinyint, but there is even an sinonymous for that, just create an column with the type as BOOL; And an Enum is very similar as it is stored as an int, with the indexes, so is the same as you initialize a enum value passing the index instead of the value; I do a lot of this mappings with enuns and booleans and its never a problem;

Comment: For the databases that there is no such thing as boolean type (ORACLE) a simple case statement casting 1 for true or 0 for false will do the trick with the boolean type

Comment: You have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I find it a lot easier to just alias the sql columns to match the c# names:

```
SELECT 
  Id,
  Item,
  type_id as TypeId
...
```

Comment: You should not do it like this due to the inability to map enums (I use a lot), and inability to map booleans since MySQL doesn't support the datatype. Sure you could cast, but its not ideal.